# Custom WPF list control

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, controls

I want to build a WPF control that works like

[image]

which is part of outlook navigation.

I am not sure weather to use a tab control or a list control.

It would be really helpful if you could refer a sample as well.

Thanks in Advance,
KD

Comment: You don't have to build your own control from scratch to achieve this. You can use this project:  http://navigationpane.codeplex.com.

Comment: Sounds to me like you can do this with standard WPF mechanisms such as `ItemTemplate` `GroupStyle` and `CollectionView`.

Comment: What's the difference between this and `Expander`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into the [`Expander`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.expander%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) control. It's a collapsible content panel where you click on the header to expand or collapse the content.

This should give you something like your "Current View" panel above:

```
<Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,2" BorderBrush="LightBlue" >
    <Expander IsExpanded="True" Name="expander" Background="#FFB5E1F3">
        <Expander.Header>
            <TextBlock Text="Current View" Background="#FFB5E1F3" Foreground="#FF166CD3" FontWeight="Bold" Padding="4,1,75,1"/>
        </Expander.Header>
        <Expander.Content>
            <Grid Background="White">
                <StackPanel Margin="20,0,0,0">
                    <RadioButton Content="Business Cards" Margin="2"/>
                    <RadioButton Content="Address Cards" Margin="2"/>
                    <RadioButton Content="Phone List" Margin="2"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Expander.Content>
    </Expander>
</Border>
```